# Magento2: How to correctly render a json in grid field

Tags: magento2, grid, json, ui

I created a field in my order grid table, I have an observer set up that will fill the field with a JSON string of the ordered items. I want to have this field rendered to HTML so the ordered items will show on order grid. However, I can not find any information on how to properly render a JSON in UI grid system of Magento 2. I am planning to share it in a public repository so I would like to have the code as clean as possible. I have the following code right now:

```
namespace Qxs\OrderLinesGrid\Ui\Component;

class Grid extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column {

  /**
  * Logger Interface
  *
  * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
  */
  protected $logger;

  public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
      \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
      \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
      array $components = [],
      array $data = []
  ){
      $this->logger = $logger;
      parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
  }

  public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
      foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
        if (!empty($item['order_lines'])) {
          $json = $item['order_lines'];
          $this->logger->debug("JSON Data".$json);
        }
      }
    }
    return $dataSource;
  }
}
```

However I cannot edit the JSON it returns an empty string, the JSON is showed in the grid but not on var_dump($json). Can anybody guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Do not add logger in foreach loop. Please add it outside.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. You have to decode your json data to see it. Check your log file. Please make sure that you are getting correct data in function.
Please check `$dataSource` array.

```
<?php namespace Qxs\OrderLinesGrid\Ui\Component;

class Grid extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column 
{

    /**
    * Logger Interface
    *
    * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
    */
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $this->logger->debug("JSON Data".json_decode($dataSource['data']['items']));
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $json = $item['order_lines'];
                //var_dump($json);
            }
        }
    return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I have updated my code but log stays empty, what file should it be?

Comment: you should check `var/log/debug.log`

Comment: paste your json result in here so that you can see it in proper format. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: json is validated by the tool, the only entry i have in debug is [2018-07-31 19:14:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://xxx/admin_77z4au/mui/index/render/?namespace=sales_order_grid&search=&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D=true&paging%5BpageSize%5D=20&paging%5Bcurrent%5D=1&sorting%5Bfield%5D=increment_id&sorting%5Bdirection%5D=desc&isAjax=true","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []

Comment: You should add my code.. The code you updated in your question is wrong. Becuase its in foreach loop and you didnt use json_decode

Comment: It returns: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /data/web/magento2_staging/app/code/Qxs/OrderLinesGrid/Ui/Component/Grid.php on line 25 on your code prob because that is an array and not json let me try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80949/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-coen-ponsen).

Comment: datasource is empty.... i think i will have to this with a html file

Comment: It was due to my data, somehow previous orders where blocking the script, after deleting the orders the code worked

Comment: Sounds good. Happy Coding :)